# What is the difference between com.sun.tools.xjc.XJC2Task and com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask

Tags: jaxb

I was having difficulty with XJCTask so am using XJC2Task to generate Jaxb classes from xsd. What is the difference?  Will the generated classes be different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XJCTask delegates to JAXB1 or JAXB2 depending on what you have on your classpath.

If you are already using JAXB2 then you wont see any difference as it ends up calling the same thing.

You are unlikely to be using JAXB1 so you can just use XJC2Task.

See a related answer with more details https://stackoverflow.com/a/8863287/1000011

Comment: thanks for the response. Yes , we finished that project and it worked with XJC2Task.